# How to add key in a nested array of Objects based on another object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array of Objects named results and have the Object which key is the key value of editKeyValues object and value needs to be add in  edit key. Below is the Input

```
var result =  [{
  name  :  'database',
  checked : true,
  key :  1,
  schemas  : [
    {
      name  : "schema2",
      checked : true,
      key : 6,
      tables : [
        {
          name  : "table2",
          checked : true,
          key : 7,
          columns : [
            {
              name  : "column1",
              checked : true,
              key : 8,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },

  ]
}]

var editKeyValues = { 8 : "column4", 6 : "schema4"}
```

Output that i want in a below format

```
    var result =  [{
      name  :  'database',
      checked : true,
      key :  1,
      schemas  : [
{
  name  : "schema2",
  checked : true,
  key : 6,
  edit : "schema4"
  tables : [
    {
      name  : "table2",
      checked : true,
      key : 7,
      columns : [
        {
          name  : "column1",
          checked : true,
          key : 8,
          edit : "column4"     // value of key 8 from editkeyValues array
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
},]}]
```

Provide me a best approach because there is large amount of data in results Object... Is recursion a good idea ???  Help me to find out the best approach.

Comment: Minimal example please.

Comment: what have you tried? btw, [JSON](https://json.org/) is a string, you have an object.

Comment: @NinaScholz edited JSON is a array If you have more clarifications comment please

Comment: No, JSON is a string, not array. What you have is an array of objects, not a JSON

Comment: @CalvinNunes Corrected!

Comment: @aviralgarg post some of the code that you did to solve this, and we can help you, otherwise, we do not do homework ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and iterate the objects and seach for nested array.

This approach uses a short circuit if no more nodes are eligible for update.

```js
function update(array, nodes) {
    return array.some(o => {
        var key = o.key.toString();
        if (nodes.has(key)) {
            o.edit = nodes.get(key);
            nodes.delete(key);
            if (!nodes.size) return true;
        }
        return update(Object.values(o).find(Array.isArray) || [], nodes);
    });
}

var data = [{ name: 'database', checked: true, key: 1, schemas: [{ name: "schema1", checked: true, key: 2, tables: [{ name: "table1", checked: true, key: 3, columns: [{ name: "column2", checked: true, key: 5 }] }] }, { name: "schema2", checked: true, key: 6, tables: [{ name: "table2", checked: true, key: 7, columns: [{ name: "column1", checked: true, key: 8 }] }] }] }],
    keyValues = { 8: 'column4', 6: 'schema4' };

update(data, new Map(Object.entries(keyValues)));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [{
  name: 'database',
  checked: true,
  key: 1,
  schemas: [
    {
      name: "schema2",
      checked: true,
      key: 6,
      tables: [
        {
          name: "table2",
          checked: true,
          key: 7,
          columns: [
            {
              name: "column1",
              checked: true,
              key: 8,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}];
let schemas = data.flatMap(d => d.schemas);
let tables = schemas.flatMap(s => s.tables);
let columns = tables.flatMap(t => t.columns);
let flatData = [data, schemas, tables, columns].flat();

let editKeyValues = {8: "column4", 6: "schema4"};
Object.entries(editKeyValues).forEach(([key, newName]) =>
    flatData.find(obj => obj.key === parseInt(key)).edit = newName);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 13,
    product_name: 'Onion Pizza',
    image: '26238.jpg',
    category: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Restaurants',
      image: 'restaurant.png',
      created_at: '2022-02-02T07:59:05.000000Z',
      updated_at: '2022-02-15T10:58:49.000000Z',
    },
    status: '1',
    created_at: '2022-02-19T12:22:09.000000Z',
    updated_at: '2022-03-02T09:43:53.000000Z',
    add_in_cart: false,
    quantity_in_cart: 0,
    add_in_wishlist: false,
    variant: [
      {
        id: 34,
        price: 140,
        quantity: 10,
        weight: '7 inch',
        discount: 20,
        product_id: 13,
        created_at: '2022-03-02T12:46:06.000000Z',
        updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:46:06.000000Z',
      },
      {
        id: 35,
        price: 350,
        quantity: 5,
        weight: '14 inch',
        discount: 20,
        product_id: 13,
        created_at: '2022-03-02T12:46:06.000000Z',
        updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:46:06.000000Z',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    product_name: 'Veg Fresh Pizza',
    image: '816404.jpg',
    category: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Restaurants',
      image: 'restaurant.png',
      created_at: '2022-02-02T07:59:05.000000Z',
      updated_at: '2022-02-15T10:58:49.000000Z',
    },
    status: '1',
    created_at: '2022-03-01T12:40:15.000000Z',
    updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
    add_in_cart: false,
    quantity_in_cart: 0,
    add_in_wishlist: false,
    variant: [
      {
        id: 30,
        price: 129,
        quantity: 1,
        weight: '7 inch',
        discount: 20,
        product_id: 15,
        created_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
        updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
      },
      {
        id: 31,
        price: 200,
        quantity: 1,
        weight: '12 inch',
        discount: 25,
        product_id: 15,
        created_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
        updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
      },
      {
        id: 32,
        price: 500,
        quantity: 1,
        weight: '18 inch',
        discount: 40,
        product_id: 15,
        created_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
        updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
      },
      {
        id: 33,
        price: 700,
        quantity: 1,
        weight: '20 inch',
        discount: 30,
        product_id: 15,
        created_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
        updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
      },
    ],
  },
];

let i = 0;
let j = 0;

for (i; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (j; j < data[i].variant.length; j++) {
    data[i].variant.forEach(e => {
      e.myKey = 0;
    });
  }
}
console.log('data : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
```

const data = [
{
id: 13,
product_name: 'Onion Pizza',
image: '26238.jpg',
category: {
id: 1,
name: 'Restaurants',
image: 'restaurant.png',
created_at: '2022-02-02T07:59:05.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-02-15T10:58:49.000000Z',
},
status: '1',
created_at: '2022-02-19T12:22:09.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-03-02T09:43:53.000000Z',
add_in_cart: false,
quantity_in_cart: 0,
add_in_wishlist: false,
variant: [
{
id: 34,
price: 140,
quantity: 10,
weight: '7 inch',
discount: 20,
product_id: 13,
created_at: '2022-03-02T12:46:06.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:46:06.000000Z',
},
{
id: 35,
price: 350,
quantity: 5,
weight: '14 inch',
discount: 20,
product_id: 13,
created_at: '2022-03-02T12:46:06.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:46:06.000000Z',
},
],
},
{
id: 15,
product_name: 'Veg Fresh Pizza',
image: '816404.jpg',
category: {
id: 1,
name: 'Restaurants',
image: 'restaurant.png',
created_at: '2022-02-02T07:59:05.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-02-15T10:58:49.000000Z',
},
status: '1',
created_at: '2022-03-01T12:40:15.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
add_in_cart: false,
quantity_in_cart: 0,
add_in_wishlist: false,
variant: [
{
id: 30,
price: 129,
quantity: 1,
weight: '7 inch',
discount: 20,
product_id: 15,
created_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
},
{
id: 31,
price: 200,
quantity: 1,
weight: '12 inch',
discount: 25,
product_id: 15,
created_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
},
{
id: 32,
price: 500,
quantity: 1,
weight: '18 inch',
discount: 40,
product_id: 15,
created_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
},
{
id: 33,
price: 700,
quantity: 1,
weight: '20 inch',
discount: 30,
product_id: 15,
created_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
updated_at: '2022-03-02T12:27:28.000000Z',
},
],
},
];

```
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    
    for (i; i < data.length; i++) {
      for (j; j < data[i].variant.length; j++) {
        data[i].variant.forEach(e => {
          e.myKey = 0;
        });
      }
    }
    console.log('data : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
```